# getAction() Not Working in 1.16.5 API?(Spigot)

Tags: java

Did they change the getAction() method in the 1.16.5 API? I've tried to use it in my code but it doesn't pop up, it used to pop up in the 1.8.8 API.

```
@EventHandler
    public static void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent e) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        Material mat = e.getPlayer().getInventory().getItemInMainHand().getType();

        int x = p.getLocation().getBlockX();
        int y = p.getLocation().getBlockY();
        int z = p.getLocation().getBlockZ();
        
        if (e.getAction) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .getAction() is not available for PlayerMoveEvent. For other events like PlayerInteractEvent it is available. What do you want to do?

Comment: I wanted to make a teleport stick but I figured it out already, still ty tho <3